# Suppress standard error message with predefined choice

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have built a form in MS Access that creates datasets for a database.
I have then implemented some code to check if all required fields have been filled before permitting the form to be closed and the dataset to be saved to the database.

All is working well, but I can't seem to suppress the standard error message created by Access telling me that I cannot save the dataset at the moment (if a required field is not filled and `Cancel` is set to true) and aksing me if I wanted to exit the form without saving.

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     If requiredFieldsNotFilled Then
           Cancel = True
     Else
           Cancel = False
     End If
End Sub
```

When `Cancel` is set to true (i.e. the required fields haven't all been filled) a standard error message is thrown by Access (Error Code 2169) which I am trying to suppress as such:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 2169 Then 
        Response = acDataErrContinue
      Else
        Response = acDataErrDisplay
    End If
End Sub
```

However, the generated error message provides a yes/no choice. 'Yes' being close the dataset without saving, 'No' being not close the dataset.
If I use the error handler as described above the default choice is taken which in this case is 'Yes' and the dataset is closed without being saved!
This is not what I want! I want 'No' to be chosen so that the user stays on the form and can correct his inputs... Any ideas on how to do that?
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such functionality is available, but you can manually stop the next close action by using the `Form_Unload` event:

```
Dim DontClose As Boolean
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 2169 Then 
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        DontClose = True
      Else
        Response = acDataErrDisplay
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
     Cancel = DontClose
     DontClose = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion already Erik!This already works as far as the dialogue is handled correctly. Unfortunately all the already entered values in the form are reset... any idea how to prevent that!